# pjweekday constants for weekday exceptions for multiple days

Tags: exception, ms-project, weekday

I've been trying to import & export workday exceptions of MS-Project from/to Excel. Daily, monthly or yearly exceptions are no problem, but weekly exceptions do cause me some trouble:

By recording, I understand that for each combination of several weekdays selected (via the tick-boxes) the property "pjWeekday" (or DaysOfWeek in the recorded code) is a specific Integer (6, 10 & 18 in the examples below).

Example of recorded code:

```
ActiveProject.BaseCalendars("Copy of Standard").Exceptions.Add Type:=6, Start:="01.01.2022", Finish:="18.01.2022", Name:="TestWeekly1", Period:=1, DaysOfWeek:=6
    ActiveProject.BaseCalendars("Copy of Standard").Exceptions.Add Type:=6, Start:="01.02.2022", Finish:="02.02.2022", Name:="TestWeekly2", Period:=1, DaysOfWeek:=10
    ActiveProject.BaseCalendars("Copy of Standard").Exceptions.Add Type:=6, Start:="01.03.2022", Finish:="03.03.2022", Name:="TestWeekly3", Period:=1, DaysOfWeek:=18
```

Is there any way to get a list of all integers for all combinations (or is an algorithm behind it) without recording all different possibilities ?

Greatful for any advice,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerated constants are documented on the Microsoft site; [here's the list for pjWeekDay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.pjweekday).

The [Exceptions.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.exceptions.add) method states the DaysOfWeek parameter is "The days on which the exception occurs. Can be a combination of PjWeekday constants." My testing indicates this is only a partial truth.

It appears that the DaysOfWeek values are *not* PjWeekday constants but rather powers of 2 that can be aggregated. For example, if the weekly exception is for Mondays, the DaysOfWeek = 2 (2^1) and for Thursdays it would be 16 (2^4). And if the exception is for Mondays and Wednesdays, the value would be 10 (2^1 + 2^3).

The formula is: the sum of `2 ^ (PjWeekday constant - 1)` for each weekday in the exception.

Comment: @Chris Glad to hear it. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)